# Help me out With Error _deflateInit2_

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/photon/Desktop/Walg-19-aug/WalgreensIPAD_1.0.3/iPad/Walgreens/../ZXingWidget/build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/photon/Desktop/Walg-19-aug/WalgreensIPAD_1.0.3/iPad/Walgreens/../ZXingWidget/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/photon/Desktop/Walg-19-aug/WalgreensIPAD_1.0.3/iPad/Walgreens/../ZXingWidget/build/Release-iphoneos'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/photon/Desktop/Walg-19-aug/WalgreensIPAD_1.0.3/iPad/Walgreens/libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneDevice.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/photon/Desktop/Walg-19-aug/WalgreensIPAD_1.0.3/iPad/Walgreens/libOmnitureAppMeasurement-iPhoneSimulator_4_0_GM.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataCompressor setupStream] in ASIDataCompressor.o
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataCompressor closeStream] in ASIDataCompressor.o
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataCompressor compressBytes:length:error:shouldFinish:] in ASIDataCompressor.o
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataDecompressor setupStream] in ASIDataDecompressor.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataDecompressor closeStream] in ASIDataDecompressor.o
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      -[ASIDataDecompressor uncompressBytes:length:error:] in ASIDataDecompressor.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OMAppMeasurement", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in OmnitureService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

i got this error Even i Included the libz1.2.5.dylib into my project.

I am working in X-Code 4.2 for IOS Beta Version

@ All

Any one please tell problem solving.

Comment: You should accept the most up-voted answer @user891268

Answer (score 71):

EDIT : As of Xcode 7 libz.dylib has been renamed to libz.tbd

I fix this problem by add libz.dylib to Link Library.

following this guide:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

Comment: As of Xcode 7 `libz.dylib` has been renamed to `libz.tbd`.

Answer (score 5):

you need to follow this set of instruction to use this API http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions, I am sure you didn't added libz.dylib in your project

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that **ALL** relevant targets have libz linked.  You could be adding it to Target A and trying to compile Target B which is missing it.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you link against libz correctly, eg. check that its included in the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase of your target.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure, but it says "for architecture i386" ... should be armv6 or armv7...
So i would check your build steps...

Comment: He builds for the iPhone simulator so a i386 target architecture is perfectly fine.

Comment: Please make sure that in your Build Settings the Point "Architecture" stands on "Standard(armv6 armv7)" or "optimized" and Base SDK is set to Latest iOS.
Might also help to run a clean once

Comment: Did you do everything described in here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions ?

Comment: hm, which version of the simulator did you start?
The newest xcode beta only ships with 4.3 and 5.0, maybe it doesn't support any other versions right now.
The build path seems mighty long too... you could try setting it manually to a shorter path, but i don't think that's really the problem :/
Did you create the Project in Xcode 3 or Xcode 4? And is the ASI project on the newest Version? I do know that there are big differences in how libraries are linked in Xcode 4 compared to how they were linked in Xcode 3

Comment: @Infinite i start with newest xcode beat 4.3 and ios 5.0...  Project created in X-Code 3 Now i upgrade to 4.2 version ios 5.0 beta.

Comment: hmm... does this also occur when building for a device instead of the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8 libz.dylib has been renamed to libz.tbd